# Storing Class in Array

Tags: java

I have n class (Class1, Class2, .., Classn), each have a static main methods.

I wish to store this class in an array, and call the main method once for each class.
But what is the type that I have to declare for this array?

This is what I have done finally according to the reply from T.J. Crowder

```
ArrayList<Class> meoa = new ArrayList(
                    Arrays.asList(Class.forName("mypackage.Class1"),
                            Class.forName("mypackage.Class2"),
                            Class.forName("mypackage.Class3"),
                            Class.forName("mypackage.Class4"),
                            Class.forName("mypackage.Class5")));    


          for(Class cls:meoa) {
              System.out.println("Invoking:"+cls.getName());
              Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
              Object[] arg = new Object[1];                  
              arg[0] = new String[] {};
              m.invoke(null, arg);
          }
```

Comment: Rather than calling list of main method, you should chain the functionalists of those methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type is `Class[]` (array of [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)). (Since `main` is a static method, we can't really use an interface for this.)

When you're ready to call `main`, you'd do that via reflection, e.g.:

```
Class[] classes = /*...create and fill in the array...*/;
for (Class cls : classes) {
    // Look up the main method accepting an array of strings
    Method m = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
    m.invoke(null, /*...see note below...*/);
}
```

Re "see note below" above: The argument you pass `invoke` is an `Object[]` (array of `Object`) containing the arguments to give `main`. Since `main` expects a single argument (an array of strings), you have to pass it a single-entry `Object[]` where that one entry is `String[]`. So for instance, if you were going to pass `["one", "two", "three"]` to `main`, you'd construct the `invoke` argument like this:

```
Object[] arg = new Object[1];                    // Room for one argument
arg[0] = new String[] { "one", "two", "three" }; // That one arg is a String array
m.invoke(null, arg);                             // Invoke main
```

(The `null` in the call to `invoke` is for the instance on which to call the method; since `main` is static, we supply `null` for that.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder any reference?

Comment: @swapnil7: Reference for what?

Comment: @swapnil7: I linked to `Class` in the JDK reference (the word `Class` in the above is a link).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java (and most statically-typed languages) can only store one type at a time. If the classes all extend the same superclass, then you can declare an array that can store all those classes as follows:

```
SuperClass[] array = new Superclass[];
```

Alternatively, if you didn't actually mean (Class1, Class2, ..., Classn) but (object1, object2, ..., objectn), where each object is an instance of some class `SomeClass`, then that's just:

```
SomeClass[] array = new SomeClass[];
```

As for calling the `main` method on each, just loop through said array and call the method.